# How do to block comments in Liberty Basic?

Tags: basic

Each day has its own data, and I need to run some science stuff without using the recent data.

Basically I need to block comment it out. How is that done in Liberty Basic?

Answer (score 6):

Liberty Basic does not support multi-line comments. it only supports these two single line formats:

```
'This is a comment
REM This is a comment
```

so the best alternative is it repeatedly type: ' + down arrow + left arrow

Some BASIC programming languages support multi-line comments like so:

```
/' This is
a multi-line
comment '/
```

Comment: Is liberty basic any good. is it worth the money and can you make windows like in VB .NET. What is really the benefit of Liberty basic over the .NET framework.

Comment: Does liberty basic have its own tag.